# Variables Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I try to execute simple variable example that i found on following [link](http://webigniter.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/storing-variables-in-selenium-ide/)

But Echo execution result is not the variable value.

What is wrong with this case?

Thanks for your answers in advance

**TestCase:**

store|example|i 
echo|{$i}|

**Log:**

```
[info] Executing: |store | example | i |
[info] Executing: |echo | {$i} | |
[info] echo: {$i}
```

Additional information:

- Firefox 30.0 - Mozilla firefox for ubuntu canonical 1.0
- Seleium IDE 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo error in your script.

Please use:

```
store | example | i
echo  | ${i}
```

instead of:

```
store | example | i
echo  | {$i}
```